# HTML Canvas ShadowBlur Not Working After Rotating

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The problem I am having is that Canvas will not draw a ShadowBlur effect when drawing my image if I rotate the Canvas at all to draw it. It works perfectly fine if I set the rotation value to 0 degrees.

I threw together a jsfiddle real fast, the image is pixelated and distorted but anyhow it reproduces the issue https://jsfiddle.net/zsw7wkv4/1/

Edit: Seems to be a Chrome only issue

Here is the code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('GameCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var asset = card.asset;

// set the card height based off the width
var height = width * 2.66;

// save the canvas before rotating
ctx.save();

// hover effect for drawn card
if (core.information.xoffset >= left && core.information.xoffset <= left + width && core.information.yoffset >= top && core.information.yoffset <= top + height) {

    ctx.shadowColor = 'white';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;

}

// translate to the center of the card
ctx.translate(core.information.pwidth * (left + width/2), core.information.pheight * (top + height/2));

// rotate the canvas for the card
ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI/180);

// translate back
ctx.translate(-core.information.pwidth * (left + width/2), -core.information.pheight * (top + height/2));

// draw the card
ctx.drawImage(asset, core.information.pwidth * left, core.information.pheight * top, core.information.pwidth * width, core.information.pheight * height);

// restore the canvas after rotating    
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet/fiddle?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle. you can use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to do that.

Comment: The image is pixelated and distorted but it does what my issue is, if the rotate value isn't set to 0 it won't have that shadow effect

https://jsfiddle.net/zsw7wkv4/1/

Comment: Cannot reproduce - I get shadow at all angles (I exaggerated color and blur): http://i.imgur.com/SMK0BP2.png

Comment: Really? On mine the shadow disappears if the value for rotation isn't 0. Is it a browser issue maybe?

Edit: Just tried it in Edge, seems like the issue only exists in Chrome. Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: The only way to fix it is to draw the shadow manually or using an image for shadow. This is of course not ideal. I would think the Chrome issue is just temporary. If you are using regular chrome try with Chrome Canary (beta) and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Sometimes issues with your graphics card drivers can affect your web browser's visual capabilities too. I remember a Catalyst update broke CSS triangles for me one time in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue.

Draw your blured image to a temp canvas first, then draw that as an image  (rotated) on your "final" canvas.